# Confusion with dispatching an action in loop and tracking progress individually

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga

I am dispatching an action let's say "GET_STATUS" in a loop for X number of time from a component.
In saga file I have

```
function* actionWatcher() {
    yield all([
        takeLatest(Actions.GET_LATEST, getLatest),
    ]);
}
```

Inside `getLatest*` function there is this API call

```
//Some code
const results = yield call(api, {params});
//code after
callback()
```

I can clearly see API being called X number of time in network and also in chrome debugger I can see `//Some code` is executed X number of time. But `//code after` is executed only once in the end and `callback` function is being called just once in the end.
I am expecting to be called for each occurrence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If multiple `Actions.GET_LATEST` happen in rapid succession, then `takeLatest` is designed to cancel the old saga, and start a new one. If the saga is canceled while it's executing `const results = yield call(api, {params});`, that means it will never get to `callback()`

If you don't want them to be canceled, then use `takeEvery` instead of `takeLatest`

```
function* actionWatcher() {
    yield all([
        takeEvery(Actions.GET_LATEST, getLatest),
    ]);
}
```

If you want to keep the cancellation, but you need the callback to be called even if it's cancelled, you can use a try/finally:

```
function* getLatest() {
  try {
    const results = yield call(api, {params});
  } finally {
    // This code will run whether it completes successfully, or throws an error, or is cancelled
    callback();
  }
}
```

If you need to specifically check whether it was cancelled in order to perform custom logic, you can do so with an `if (yield cancelled())` in the finally block:

```
function* getLatest() {
  try {
    const results = yield call(api, {params});
    callback(); // This line will only run if it's not cancelled and does not throw
  } finally {
    if (yield cancelled()) {
      // This line will only run if cancelled
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I just wonder if `all([takeEvery...])` is even correct. The `getLatest` calls can happen with a delay. Won't `all` be called multiple times?

Comment: `actionWatcher` is, i assume, the saga that's passed in when initializing redux saga. It will be run exactly once. The `all` isn't necessary in the current code, but i assume they intend to add other sagas.

Comment: takeEvery is apparently working fine. I'm testing right now. Will update in a while. Also yes there are other sagas too.